# How to locate a check box based on the following html - Selenium WebDriver and C#

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I'm trying to enable specific check boxes contained within a page.  Please see the HTML code below

```
<div class="form-horizontal">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label for="Url_url_option1">Option 1</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-1">
                <input type="checkbox" data-yesno-name="Url_option1" class="url-field-toggle">
        <span class="glyphicon clickable glyphicon-remove" id="toggle_undefined"></span>
                <input id="Url_option1" name="Url.url_option1" type="hidden" value="no">
                &nbsp;
            </div>


            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label for="Url_option2">Option 2</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-1">
                <input type="checkbox" data-yesno-name="Url_option2" class="url-field-toggle">
        <span class="glyphicon clickable glyphicon-remove" id="toggle_undefined"></span>
                <input id="Url_option2" name="Url.option2" type="hidden" value="no">
                &nbsp;
            </div>


            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label for="Url_option3">Option 3</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-1">
                <input type="checkbox" data-yesno-name="Url_option3" class="url-field-toggle">
        <span class="glyphicon clickable glyphicon-remove" id="toggle_undefined"></span>
                <input id="Url_option3" name="Url.option3" type="hidden" value="no">
                &nbsp;
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                &nbsp;
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label for="Url_option4">Option 4</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-1">
                <input type="checkbox" data-yesno-name="Url_option4" class="url-field-toggle">
        <span class="glyphicon clickable glyphicon-remove" id="toggle_undefined"></span>
                <input id="Url_option4" name="Url.option4" type="hidden" value="no">
                &nbsp;
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label for="Url_option5">Option 5</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-1">
                <input type="checkbox" data-yesno-name="Url_option5" class="url-field-toggle">
        <span class="glyphicon clickable glyphicon-remove" id="toggle_undefined"></span>
                <input id="Url_option5" name="Url.option5" type="hidden" value="no">
                &nbsp;
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label for="Url_option6">Option 6</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-1">
                <input type="checkbox" data-yesno-name="Url_option6" class="url-field-toggle">
        <span class="glyphicon clickable glyphicon-remove" id="toggle_undefined"></span>
                <input id="Url_option6" name="option6" type="hidden" value="no">
                &nbsp;
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

All of the check box elements apepar to be unique so I can use standard by locators to find each checkbox but, when I try to click on any of them, I can an "Element not found" exception.
Is the "Hidden" type preventing these buttons from being clicked on?

The only way I can sucessfully click on a check box is by finding and clicking on the following element:

```
<span class="glyphicon clickable glyphicon-remove" id="toggle_undefined"></span>
```

by using an xpath locator:

```
//*[@id="toggle_undefined"]
```

This works ok.  The click event gets fired sucessfully to the checkbox but this will obviously only fire the click to the first element (check box) on the page.

Let's assume I wanted to use this xpath locator to click on the second check box from the second row, how would I make the xpath unique for each element (check box) on the page?

From the HTML code above, this is the second check box from the second row:

```
 <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label for="Url_option5">Option 5</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-1">
                <input type="checkbox" data-yesno-name="Url_option5" class="url-field-toggle">
        <span class="glyphicon clickable glyphicon-remove" id="toggle_undefined"></span>
                <input id="Url_option5" name="Url.option5" type="hidden" value="no">
                &nbsp;
            </div>
```

Comment: You can always use index in xpath as
    //*[@id="toggle_undefined"][2]

Comment: So what is the problem? You cannot locate other checkboxes or you can, but they cannot be clicked? Share your code + exception log

Comment: @DebanjanB I updated my previous question with this edit but you told me to open a new question.  None of the answers work for me because I didn't provide enough information in the original question.  I failed to mention that I needed the xpath to be unique because the elements couldn't be clicked on

Comment: @Banjaxx You haven't mentioned if you have tried any of the solutions provided by the contributors. Perhaps you should provide a feedback to each of the answers.

Comment: @Banjaxx Sorry for the confusion. DebanjanB should not have rolled back your edit to the other question. I've fixed it now. Please delete this question since it's a duplicate of your original question and add any details to the original. Thanks.

Comment: @JeffC It will not allow me to delete it

Comment: I'm assuming it's telling you that you can't delete a question that has answers? If so, just flag your own question and explain that you need to delete it because it's a duplicate of the other question and a moderator should delete it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in your case you can uniquely identify your checkbox element by simply using the `data-yesno-name` attribute of your checkbox input element. An example xpath to locate the option 5 checkbox:

```
//input[@type='checkbox' and @data-yesno-name='Url_option5']
```

If you click on this element, it will work fine.

Also, you can uniquely identify the required checkbox with the following strategy :

Suppose you want the checkbox beside "Option 5". Now the `<div>` containing this checkbox is immediately next to the `<div>` containing the text "Option 5". So you can find the checkbox relative to this texts with this xpath:

```
//label[contains(text(),'Option 5')]//ancestor::div[@class='col-sm-3']/following-sibling::div[@class='col-sm-1']//input[@type='checkbox']
```

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for.  Let me try it

Comment: @Banjaxx any update? Did it solve the problem?